# Error 404 page not found after rewrite url from custom post type if exist other param

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

This is default link from custom post type:

```
domain.com/course/mern-stack-front-to-back-full-stack-react-redux-node-js
```

I am trying to create a custom rewrite rule if exist params is meta_id

```
domain.com/course/mern-stack-front-to-back-full-stack-react-redux-node-js?meta_id=1234
```

Should become this:

```
domain.com/course/mern-stack-front-to-back-full-stack-react-redux-node-js/lesson/1234
```

This is my code in functions.php

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%meta_id%', '([^&]+)' );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^lesson/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?post_type=course&meta_id=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%meta_id%', '([^&]+)' );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^course/([^/]*)/lesson/([0-9]+)/?','index.php?post_type=course&name=$matches[1]&meta_id=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please improve your answer according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer